# Why my URL doesn't activate view in django?

Tags: python, django

Here is the thing i'm trying to do:

1. There are few tv channels as image links and they will have some information inside channels.
2. I managed to create tv channels as a list, they look like a link but they don't work like link.

I've created slug area for each channel that takes from it's own name and generates slug auto. And with get_absolute_url i take it's url in the below code you'll see;

This is my model :

```
class Channels(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Tv Kanalı")
   logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="channels/images/", verbose_name="Tv Logosu", blank=False)
   slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True, editable=True)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.slug = slugify(self.name)
       super(Channels, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('channel-list:campaigns', kwargs={'page_slug': self.slug})
```

This is my main urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'', include(('tvekstra.apps.core.urls', 'home'), namespace='home')),
   url(r'^user/', include(('tvekstra.apps.user.urls', 'login'), namespace='user')),
   url(r'^channels/', include(('tvekstra.apps.tvchannels.urls', 'main'), namespace="channel-list")),
```

This is channels urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'', views.channel_list, name='channels'),
   url(r'^(?P<page_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.campaign_list, name='campaigns'),
```

]

This is my views:

```
def channel_list(request):
   channels = Channels.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'channel.list.html', {'channels': channels})

def campaign_list(request, page_slug):
   channel = get_object_or_404(Channels, slug=page_slug)
   return render(request, 'campaign.list.html', {'channel': channel})
```

And this is my template:

```
{% for channel in channels %}
    <div class="col-3 text-center channels">
        <a href="{{ channel.get_absolute_url }}">
            <img src="{{ channel.get_image }}" alt="Channel Image" class="ch-img">
            {{ channel.name }}
        </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, a href is channel's getabsoluteurl method. It creates the html but it doesn't go forward page.
I think view is not working for some reason, requesting aid...

Comment: Exactly what is the `href=""` in the *rendered* result. Can you inspect the source code of the web page?

Comment: It returns : <a href="/channels/fox/"> , fox is one of the channels name generated as slug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url(r'',` matches `''`, but it also matches `/channels/fox/` and `/something-else/`.

You can fix it by adding `^$` to the regex.

```
url(r'^$', views.channel_list, name='channels'),
```

In Django 2.0+, it would be better to use `re_path`, because `url` is deprecated in Django 3.1:

```
re_path(r'^$', views.channel_list, name='channels'),
```

And it would be simpler to use `path`:

```
path('', views.channel_list, name='channels'),
```

Comment: Well yes that works like  charm. I just couldn't understand what is difference between url(r' ') ..... and path(' ')

Comment: `url` and `re_path` take regexes, and the regex `r''` matches every string. The `path` syntax is simpler, and `''` only matches `''`.